# Sorting Delimited Text File Php

Tags: php

I have a text file that i would like to sort via PHP and i'm kinda stumped since sort() or asort() would sort the first letter(s) in the line rather than a specific part

I would read all texts to an array line using

```
    $list = array(file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

but how would you implement a sort()?

So my text file contains

```
    Name1→Text1→1→1→1062166→3499999999
    Name2→Text2→1→1→1332130→1999999999
    Name3→Text3→1→1→1040121→8249999999
    Name4→Text4→1→1→1060075→7249999999
    Name5→Text5→1→1→1402172→249999999
    Name6→Text6→1→1→1222044→199999999
    Name7→Text7→1→1→1542015→299999999
```

I would like the output to be seperated by the last number so the output should be

```
    Name6→Text6→1→1→1222044→199999999
    Name5→Text5→1→1→1402172→249999999
    Name7→Text7→1→1→1542015→299999999
    Name2→Text2→1→1→1332130→1999999999
    Name1→Text1→1→1→1062166→3499999999
    Name4→Text4→1→1→1060075→7249999999
    Name3→Text3→1→1→1040121→8249999999
```

Comment: There's `usort()`. You can have your own comparison function there that does the trick.

Comment: `fgetcsv`, create array, `usort` array, `fputcsv` to _new_ file (you can't sort an existing file...), on success (make sure!), unlink old file, move new file to old file's position.

Answer (score 1):

you can loop and build an array with your key and sort that array and get your values back. in the below code sample i have used `→` as a literal value but if you were meaning the tab char replace `→` with `\t`. you can also use `explode`

```
$list = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$new = array();
foreach ($list as $item) {
    preg_match("/^(.*)(→[^→]+)$/", $item, $matches);
    $new[$matches[1]] = $item; 
}

ksort($new);

$list = array_values($new);
```

Comment: I think the OP meant \t ... → was just the notation chosen to show that....but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I'm assuming by `→` you mean {tab})

```
$fp = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = array();
while($contents[] = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t"){}
fclose($fp);
usort($contents, function($a, $b) {return strnatcmp($a[5],$b[5]); });
```

Note this syntax requires php 5.3+

**NOTE**

Changed to return strnatcmp to keep numbers from overflowing.